# How to merge the current branch into another branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches, master and dev. I always work on dev and only check code into the master branch once it's been approved for production use. When I do so, I have to do the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git checkout dev
```

That's awfully verbose, and since I do it frequently, I'd like to minimize it. Is there any one git command I can use to merge from my current branch dev to the other branch master without having to checkout the master branch first? Something maybe like:

```
git merge dev to master
```

would be awesome. I looked through the git documentation and didn't see anything.

Comment: Have you tried using git push for this?

Comment: What's with the suggestions of push? That's for updating *remotes*, not merging within one's own repository.

Comment: Jefromi is right, push is not useful here. I'm talking about another local branch, not a remote branch.

Comment: Even worse is when you have uncommitted local changes: `git stash`, `git checkout master`, `git merge dev`, `git checkout dev`, `git stash pop`.

Comment: Nice question. I wanted this too because I wanted to pull into a non-current branch. I wanted to avoid switching branches because I have a process that kicks off a build if any files in the working tree change.

Comment: Just for clarification; @Jefromi is wrong. Pushing works with any git filesystem, local or "_remote_".

Comment: @Qix, that's not what he said. You cannot do a push between two branches in the same repo. Push is for moving changes between repos, not within the same repo on different branches.

Comment: @Qix Pushing does work with remote repositories on any filesystems including local, but it does not do the same thing as merge. You can use it to push to a branch in your own repository as shown in the accepted answer, but that will only work if the merge is a fast-forward, so it is most definitely *not* the same thing as merging. That's why I actually used merge in my answer.

Comment: Unless you `--force` @Jefromi.

Comment: @Qix I'm sure you're aware that doesn't make push able to do what merge does. Forcing one branch to point to a commit is not the same thing as merging, and if you tell people to do it instead of merging, five minutes later half of them are going to be looking for an answer telling them how to use git reflog to figure out what that branch they just overwrite used to point to.

Comment: Right; that's not what the OP is asking for, I understand that. I'm just pointing out that it *is* possible to push locally; your comment by itself was wrong without the context of the OP. `@Jefromi was wrong` was probably bad wording.

Comment: Somehow your use case suggests that you're always doing a fast-forward merge on master. In that case you could simply force the master pointer to move using `git branch -f master dev`. (Assuming you are the sole contributor of the repo.)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**1.** Add a remote alias for your local repository, ex:

```
git remote add self file:///path/to/your/repository
```

(Or on windows `git remote add self C:\path\to\your\repository`)

**2.** Push to the self remote, ex:

```
git push self dev:master
```

Comment: Submodules! Not only does this solve the problem of the question asked, but it also solves the problem of switching branches when having just a submodule. Great tip!

Comment: +1 This is creative, and doesn't touch the working tree at all. Just a clarification: the `/path/to/your/repository` is the path to your working tree, i.e. don't include the `.git` directory. Also, this should go without saying: the remote will have to be updated if you move the repo.

Comment: I'm not having any luck getting this to work in windows... `git remote add self file:///c/projects` just comes back with the usage notes

Comment: Ok, it just needed quotes because one of the actual subdirs in the path had spaces

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss You can first merge master into current branch (`dev`) and then push the merge commit using `git push self dev:master`.

Comment: @LeonidShvechikov Yes, but that will have the parentage in the reverse order.

Comment: Why the remote alias? `.` worked fine for me: `git push . head:master` .

Comment: Says everything is up-to-date when I try to push the self remote to the branch.  But the branch doesn't exist in Github anywhere.

Comment: I personally prefer the alias solution from @Dmytrii below

Comment: @Maslow you can use a normal drive path, instead of a file: URL. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 64):

The current highest-voted answer by @zerome is a good one, but is a bit needlessly verbose.

In the base of your git repo you can just do this: `git push . dev:master`

A more generalised solution that would work anywhere in the tree would be:

```
git push $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) dev:master
```

Comment: `git push . dev:master` simplified my life a lot ! Best answer by far, thank you

Comment: are you going to push the merged master to a remote repository like github? save a step by doing `git push origin dev:master`

Comment: Is it possible to replicate the `merge --no-ff` behaviour with this?

Comment: I'm getting *Invalid remote name "."* in Windows. Do I still need to do `git remote add self file:///myRepo`?

Comment: But this doesn't really do a merge... It will work if dev is ahead of master, but what if it's not?

Answer (score 45):

Your best bet would be to just use an alias, placed in your global gitconfig (`~/.gitconfig`):

```
[alias]
    merge-to = "!f() { git checkout $1 && git merge $2 && git checkout -; }; f"
```

so that you can invoke it from any repository as

```
git merge-to master dev
```

Comment: What would happen if the merge is not automatic, but requires merge resolution? (In this case I assume no work is done on master, so it wouldn't happen, but still)...

Comment: @Stein: Since I used `&&`, not `;`, it would fail the merge, and not try to switch back. Hopefully the user is smart enough to see the "merge failed" message and deal with it.

Comment: @Stein: If you happen to know that the merge should be a fast-forward, you could do it without checking out at all, but the OP didn't seem to be in that case.

Comment: I prefer this `merge-to = "!f() { export tmp_branch=`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '`; git checkout $1 && echo git merge $tmp_branch && echo git checkout $tmp_branch; unset $tmp_branch; }; f"`, it let's me not have to type in the branch I'm currently on, so if I want to merge `dev` into `master` and I'm on `dev` right now I just type `git merge-to master`

Comment: Better version with correct backticks and without echo: `merge-to = "!f() { export tmp_branch=\`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '\`; git checkout $1 && git merge $tmp_branch && git checkout $tmp_branch; unset $tmp_branch; }; f"`

Comment: the unset command is not correct. fixed is:
    merge-to = "!f() { export tmp_branch=`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '`; git checkout $1 && git merge --no-ff $tmp_branch && git checkout $tmp_branch; unset tmp_branch; }; f"

Answer (score 38):

A little modification from Jefromi alias that doesn't require you to type in the current branch.

So you use it like: `git merge-to dev`.

This will switch over to the `dev` branch, merge it with CURRENT and then will switch back.

For example, assuming you are on `master` branch, it will merge the master into dev and you will still be on the master.

It definitely goes to my dotfiles :)

```
[alias]
  merge-to = "!gitmergeto() { export tmp_branch=`git branch | grep '* ' | tr -d '* '` && git checkout $1 && git merge $tmp_branch && git checkout $tmp_branch; unset tmp_branch; }; gitmergeto"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is old, but...

Combining the solutions from @kevin-lyda and @dmytrii-nagirniak above. this alias merges the current branch into the specified branch. It uses the remotes method with and uses git commands to get the context.

```
[alias]
    merge-to = "!gitmergeto() { git push \"`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`\" `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`:$1; } && gitmergeto"
```

To be used like:

```
git merge-to other-branch-name
```

Answer (score 5):

To merge the current branch into another branch without checking out the other branch:

### Fast-forward merge

This is really easy. By definition, a fast-forward merge simply means the branch pointer is moved ahead in the commit tree. So all you need to do is just *simulate* that:

```
git branch -f master dev
```

> **Caveats:** This assumes that `master` points to a commit that is also in `dev` branch or some other branch. If it doesn't, **you risk losing work!** Unlike `git merge` which will create a merge commit (or complain) when fast-forward is not possible, this method **silently forces** the branch pointer to point to another commit.
>
> This also assumes you're the only one working on the repo, and/or you know what you're doing.

**Tip:** If you did a `git fetch` and you have new commits in `origin/master`, you can move the `master` branch without checking out using:

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

### Merge via merge commit

This is not always possible. To create a merge commit, you have to do a merge operation. And to do a merge operation, you should have commits in the other branch that are not in the current branch.

If you do have commits in the `master` branch which are **not** in `dev` branch, you can:

> **Disclaimer:** This is merely a proof-of-concept, just to show it's *sometimes* possible to do a merge to the other branch without checking out. If you would want to use it everyday, you probably want to make an alias for it using shell redirection or make a shell script for it. Then again, you can also make a shell script for the shorter process shown in the question.

```
git checkout -b temp
git merge --no-ff -e master
git branch -f master temp
git checkout dev
git branch -D temp
```

**Explanation:**

1. Check out a temporary branch that points to the same commit as current branch.
2. Merge `master` into the temporary branch and launch commit message editor. If you want the merge commit to *look like* you had merged the `dev` branch into `master`, edit it from this:

   ```
   Merge branch 'master' into temp
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   Merge branch 'dev'
   ```

   *Tip:* You can use `-m "Merge branch 'dev'"` instead of `-e` to be quicker.
3. Update the `master` branch pointer to point to the merge commit.
4. Check out the `dev` branch.
5. Force delete the temporary branch.

This still touches your working tree, but minimally so. It doesn't roll back the tree all the way to state of the original `master` just to bring in the development changes once again. *Some may not care, but for others it may be important.*

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times you're coming from the branch you would like to merge the current branch into. In that case you could do:

`git co - && git merge @{-1}`

for example:

```
git checkout somebranch      // (while on master)

// add some commits

git co - && git merge @{-1}  // will merge somebranch into master
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to the other answers, with the following differences:

- the function is split into multiple lines for readability
- the function calls `set -ex` so each command is printed and if command fails function exits right away
- alias passes its arguments except the first (target branch) to `git merge`
- the function includes a null command `: git merge` which makes sure tab-completion works with some shell setups (e.g. [`gitfast`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/gitfast/git-completion.bash#L26-L30) from oh-my-zsh)

```sh
[alias]
  merge-to = "!f() { : git merge ; \
      set -ex ; \
      local this=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) ; \
      local target=$1 ; \
      shift ; \
      git checkout $target ; \
      git merge $this \"$@\" ; \
      git checkout $this ; \
    } ; f"
```