# Merge remote changes into a branch that is not the current branch

Tags: git, merge

I have multiple branches, and I would like to merge remote changes into a branch that **is not my current branch**.

For example:

```
git merge remote/branch some-other-branch
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't switch to that branch to do the merge? You can use `git stash` to temporarily store any uncommitted work on your current branch.

Comment: Not sure about OPs situation, but I have the case where I want to do  this in a repo that may be being used by another process. Ie, the process is working on some branch X, and is expecting the current branch to be X, and I want to update branch Y.

Comment: @ezod: Because Visual Studio's file system watcher will want to reload 30 projects.

Answer (score 29):

This is doable only if the local branch can be fast-forwarded to the remote head. While in any branch, to fetch the remote branch from origin and update the local head use:

```
git fetch origin remote_branch:local_branch
```

Essentially, this is the reverse of how you open a new branch at origin with `git push -u origin local_branch:remote_branch`.

Answer (score 3):

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788245/1173869) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/git-merge-to-another-branch) that might do what you want.

From your repo root:

```
git push . remote/branch:some-other-branch
```

This worked for me when I wanted to fast-forward master to a later commit just before I rebased to it from the branch I was in (not master).

Comment: This does the opposite the OP want, the question was to merge *remote* changes *into local* non-current branch

Answer (score -1):

I would say this is not possible, by design. From the man

```
DESCRIPTION
       Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their
       histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.
```