# Git: error when fetching master from origin

Tags: git

I've been using the following command to update the local `master` when I'm *not* on `master`:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

However, today, it stopped working on one of the repo clones I'm working on. It fails with an error:

```
fatal: refusing to fetch into branch 'refs/heads/master' checked out at '/path/to/project/directory'
```

On another clone of the same repo it works fine. Any idea what might be the cause? Note that I am **not** on the `master` branch when invoking the command.

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115) with Git 2.38.0 from Homebrew.

More info (anonymized):

```
$ git worktree list
/path/to/project/directory  aa00aa0a0a0 [my-current-branch]
```

```
$ git branch -vv
  main                 bb11bb1b1b1 Title of the commit on main
  master               cc22cc2c2c2 [origin/master] Title of the commit on master
* my-current-branch    aa00aa0a0a0 [origin/my-current-branch] Title of the commit on my-current-branch
```

There are more branches on the list but that shouldn't be relevant. You can see `master` & `my-current-branch` are up to date and `main` is not right now.

Also:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:my-org/my-repo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:my-org/my-repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    main                 tracked
    master               tracked
    my-current-branch    tracked
```

The output here is huge as we have a lot of branches but other ones should be irrelevant. There's only a single remote: `origin`.

Comment: I _think_ that you have a worktree that is using that branch. Can you check with `git worktree list`?

Comment: @eftshift0 no, it doesn't include that branch; the only thing printed is: `/path/to/project/directory  aa00aa0a0a0 [my-current-branch]`.

Comment: The previous git error seems to suggest that master is checked out at that directory?

Comment: What is your current branch? The error message claims that it is `master`.

Comment: OK.... Maybe this kind of makes sense. If you are on `master`, why do you specify `master:master`? Sounds like git is making an extra check because of that. Try `git fetch origin master`

Comment: Actually... you are not _pulling_.... that syntax for fetching looks _funky_ to me, though I might be wrong as git didn't complain.

Comment: I am _not_ on master. That's the problem.

Comment: This is a common syntax for synchronizing a branch you are not on to its remote version and it worked fine so far...

Comment: I see, interesting. Glad to know you were able to solve. I, personally, try to avoid having local copies of remote branches _but_ I know it's not a particularly popular approach.

Comment: I was not able to solve the issue. I still don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Are there changes in master that do not exist in the remote? As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40125870/10871900) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/10871900), it needs to be able to be fast-forwarded. If you want to do a non fast-forward merge, try `git fetch origin +master:master` but not sure what would happen with merge conflicts...

Comment: But the best solution is probably to stash, checkout, pull, checkout and pop the stash again as that would allow you to deal with merge conflicts etc.

Comment: There are no changes on the local `master` that don't exist on the remote. Even if I checkout `master`, do a (successful) `git pull` and return to the original branch and invoke `git fetch origin master:master`, it still fails. At this point, the local & remote `master` point to the same commit and yet it still fails.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -vv` and `git remote show origin`?

Comment: @dan1st I added this info to the question as it's too large for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
fatal: refusing to fetch into branch 'refs/heads/master' checked out at '/path/to/project/directory'
```

indicates that Git is certain that there is an added working tree.  You should be able to see this working tree in `git worktree list` output, but if your Git is modern enough—and 2.38.0 certainly is—it should *also* show up in `git branch -vv` output, e.g.:

```
$ git worktree add ../xxx -b foo
Preparing worktree (new branch 'foo')
...
$ git branch -vv
+ foo             c3ff4ce (<path ending in xxx>) <commit subject>
* main            c3ff4ce <same commit subject>
  ...
$
```

What could have happened is that you *did* have an added working tree, but then you removed it, and `git worktree prune` cleaned it up:

```
$ git worktree list
<path1>                      c3ff4ce [main]
<path2, ending in xxx>       c3ff4ce [foo]
$ rm -rf ../xxx
$ git worktree prune
$ git worktree list
<path1>                      c3ff4ce [main]
$
```

Note that `git worktree prune` is a period maintenance task that `git gc --auto` will run if and when it thinks it should.  (If you use `git worktree remove` to remove added working trees, pruning never does anything, but since it was designed with this kind of lazy update ever since Git 2.5 added `git worktree add`, the maintenance tasks still have to check.)

As for `git fetch origin master:master` itself, you added in a comment:

> This is a common syntax for synchronizing a branch you are not on to its remote version and it worked fine so far...

I would not call it *common* myself, though it is known and mentioned in various StackOverflow answers.  I would not recommend its use: don't do that, just refer to `origin/master` directly when you want to get the current hash ID stored in `origin/master`.  If you're not actually using `master` here for anything, just go ahead and delete it entirely, so that you're not tempted to use it.

The one remaining note I'd add here is that since you're using a homebrew-installed Git on macOS, be aware of (and careful about) the multiple-Git-version issue: there's probably a `/usr/local/bin/git` or `/opt/.../git` *and* a `/usr/bin/git`, one being the Apple Git and one being the homebrew Git.  Which one any particular command runs will depend on `$PATH`.

Comment: `git worktree list` only shows my current branch. `git branch -vv` only prepends my current branch with `*` and no branch is prepended with `+`. I added these to my original post.

Comment: Has the problem also stopped occurring?

Comment: There are valid reasons to want a current version of `master` locally, e.g. a tool I use to count the size of produced JS assets in one of my projects caches the values per branch and then shows a summary. If I want to have the data for `master` presented, I have to have it locally. I'm sure there are other reasons as well.

Comment: No, the problem is still there.

Comment: OK, then you have a setup ripe for debugging. Build a debug version of Git, plant a breakpoint at the place that reports this, and see what's going on. (Build on macOS is kind of a pain; I run a Linux VM with Ubuntu and build there, on my mac, for any Git development I do, but the problem might not show up there.)

Comment: I must be using the Homebrew version, `which git` returns `/usr/local/bin/git`. All the commands, etc., work in the same way in the new Terminal tab as well.

Comment: @torek If you don't recommend `git fetch origin master:master`, can you be explicit about the alternative git command you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, and it had nothing to do with worktrees. In my case, I still had a bisect going, and the `master` branch was checked out outside the rebase. Check your `git status` to be safe.