# What's the most efficient way to switch to latest code master with git?

Tags: git

Let's assume I've been working on a bug fix branch for about a day, on branch Bug123.  Now I want to merge this to master.   I believe the standard practice is to do this:

```
git checkout master
git pull --tags
git merge Bug123
```

This is fine, but what's happening behind the scenes before the actual merge is this:

1. I start with working directory codebase pointing to Bug123
2. I switch to the codebase pointing to my copy of master since my last pull, say a day ago.
3. I switch to the codebase where origin/master is now

So I'm switch the codebase twice.  In fact, I have no use for the codebase in step 2.  I really don't care what master was a day ago, yet I'm switching my codebase to it.

What I found to be more efficient is this:

(again, let's assume I'm on the Bug123 branch)

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -B master
git merge Bug123
```

By doing this, I'm switching the codebase only once, and I'm never going back to old state of master.

[update]
@max630 suggested merging the middle two lines into a single:

```
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

[/update]

I've also found this technique to be useful in the case where I have a really old local codebase.   I go to it, I just do:

```
git checkout master
git pull --tags
```

And I get a bunch of merge conflicts.  I don't want do any merges.   I just want the latest codebase.   So instead, I do the same thing:

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -B master
```

This works.   But I'm just not sure this is the right way.  I mean, I think my Use Cases is extremely main-stream, so it feels odd having to do weird things like "git checkout -B".   It seems hackish to me.   Is there a better way?

To keep this question constructive, I'm not looking for subjective opinions.   An acceptable answer will be an alternative to the above that achieves the same result, which is that it reduces the number times the codebase is switched as compared to the original workflow at the top of this question.

Please note that this question is different from "[How to merge the current branch into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/how-to-merge-the-current-branch-into-another-branch)".   That question has to do with reducing the number of commands.  I'm not concerned about the number of commands I have to issue.   My concern is swapping the working-directory back and forth unnecessarily.   And none of the answers in that question address the issue I raised here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - merge to another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/git-merge-to-another-branch)

Comment: In your solution (`fetch`, `checkout origin/master`, `checkout -B master`), where do you actually merge your `bug123` branch into master? As far as I can see, you only switch to `origin/master`, reset `master` to the same commit and then switch to `master`. I might be missing something but your bugfix will not be in `master` at that point?

Comment: As for the other solution, I think `git checkout master`, `git fetch` and `git reset origin/master` should do the trick... Of course you will lose all changes that are not in `origin/master`.

Comment: What's wrong with switching twice?

Comment: you can save one command by both switching branch and checking out: `git checkout -B master origin/master`

Comment: max630, that's very useful.

Comment: axiac, switching twice can cause a performance delay when the code base has changed significantly.   Most of the time an extra second or two is not a problem.   On occasion it will take 10-15 seconds that I would like to avoid, if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: nic, my example, i left out the merge part because that's not the part I'm trying to optimize.   I'm trying to optimize the number of switches of the code-base.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to avoid switching twice is hitting:

```
git fetch origin master:master
git checkout master
git merge Bug123
```

The first fetch will update your local branch `master`.

Comment: Meyer, I like this, and will accept the answer shortly.   By the way, what is master:master in the fetch line, and why does it say 'master' twice?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) _The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source ref <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref <dst>._ **Therefore**, _if <dst> is **not empty string**, the local ref that matches it is **fast-forwarded** using <src>_ That's why you need to specify master twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `rebase`, here is example:

```
# you are in branch Bug123
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git checkout -B master
```

You are doing all in one way without switching to the codebase twice, just take latest changes from remote `master`, add them to current branch `Bug123` and move result (latest changes from remote `master` with changes from `Bug123`) to `master`.