# How to copy current state of master branch into another branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

Have tried the accepted answer on this page here:  [How to merge the current branch into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/how-to-merge-the-current-branch-into-another-branch)

But the problem is, the master doesn't have any changes needed, and I created the branch with:  `git checkout -b mybranch`

When I try `git push self mybranch:master`

It tells me that Everything up-to-date.  But I know that.  I just want to copy branch to another so that it has the current state of the master branch.  And it will not ever be touched again.

I will only be branching off of the master branch in the future.  This other branch will never actually be touched.  But I need to archive it so that if need-be, I can switch to that branch and bring it back whenever...

How to copy master branch without creating a New Repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [answer by Zoli Szabo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39902512/112968), you should use [tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) to mark events in history which should never move. To create a tag, simply provide its name and the commit it should point to. If you provide a branch name instead of a commit hash, the tag will point to the current tip commit of this branch.

```
git tag mytag branch
git tag mytag 123ab45ef
```

But to answer your question, if you want your branch to reflect the current state of master, you have a handful of options:

- Force updating the branch: `git branch -f mybranch master`, then pushing the branch
- Pushing the state you want to the branch in the remote repository: `git push origin master:mybranch` (`-f` if you need a force update). Careful, as this might cause problems to other people
- Merging the branch with the `ours` strategy (`-s ours`), to create a new commit with the wanted state. Then pushing to the remote repository.

If you simply want to update your local repository, either merge the branches (should result in a fast-forward, if I've understood your question correctly), or do a local push.

- Merge: `git checkout master; git merge mybranch`
- Local push: `git push . mybranch:master`

A push is kind of the reverse of a fast-forward merge (target and destination branches switched).

Take your pick :)

Comment: `git branch -f original:master` this gives me not a valid branch `original:master` but the original branch exists. `git branch -a` shows original in there.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: sorry, that colon was not supposed to be there. It should have been a space character.

Comment: Thanks, I just used a tag, hopefully that will do what I want.

Comment: I had to `git push --force` as `master` branch was a few (useless) `commits` behind.

Answer (score 1):

For marking specific points in history, you should use ***[tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)***, not "abandoned" branches.

Comment: agreed.  A tag expresses better that the commit chain is not in active development.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two master branches that point to different commits.  A branch only points to one commit.  To save where the master branch was at this time, create a tag on it, or make a new branch.  You can, save one branch under the name MYSUBDIR/master and a different one under the name MYOTHERSUB/master.

to create a branch 'MySave/master' on remote 'self' whose tip is the same as your local mybranch.

```
git push self mybranch:MySave/master
```

assuming you have appropriate permissions of course.  You can see the state of both branches with:

```
git log --oneline --decorate -9 mybranch self/MySave/master
```

the 'self/MySave/master' is your remote tracking copy, to get the most recent do this:

```
git fetch self self/MySave/master
```

which updates 'self/MySave/master' (but not your local 'mybranch', for that use pull)