# Is a git user not supposed to merge INTO another branch?

Tags: git, merge

From my limited understanding, when I want to merge a branch with git, I need to be *in the branch into which* I want to merge.

However, I'd like to merge *from the current branch into another branch*, but that doesn't seem easily possible (although there are some solutions on the internet for that).

So, I guess that I am actually not supposed to merge into another branch. Is this the case and if so, why?

**Edit** It was suggested that this question is a duplicate of [How to merge the current branch into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/how-to-merge-the-current-branch-into-another-branch). However, I am not asking on *how* to merge inot another branch, but rather *why* git discourages a user to merge into another branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge the current branch into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672073/how-to-merge-the-current-branch-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why merging always happen in the current branch.

Think what happens when the merge fails because of conflicts. `git merge` stops and leaves the working tree in a conflicting state, waiting for the developer to resolve the conflicts before it can continue.

But the working tree always reflects the status of the current branch (plus any changes that were operated on it since it was checked out). Allowing to merge in a different branch requires to checkout the destination branch first, do the merge then checkout the previous branch. Or exit without restoring the previous branch when the merge fails.

Jumping from one branch to another is confusing for the developer and could easily be a source of human errors.

Also, it's possible to merge more than two branches in a single `git merge` operation; allowing the merge in a different branch only complicates the command line and, again, produces confusing results if the merge fails.

Even more, the usual workflows merge changes into the current branch. One merges the changes from `master` into a long-term feature branch they are working on, to avoid encountering conflicts when feature branch is merge back into `master`. Or, when one merges the feature branch back into `master`, the feature branch is usually deleted because it is not needed any more.

Also, after a merge it's recommended to run the test suite, to ensure the changes do not bring errors. Running the test suite on the merge commit requires having the merge commit checked out in the working directory.

I cannot imagine why somebody needs to merge the current branch into another branch and what is its usefulness.