# How to merge current branch into another with --no-ff option without checkout?

Tags: git

The current branch `feature` is ahead of `master` by several commits and is to be merged into `master` with `--no-ff` option. This can be achieved by

```bash
git checkout master
git merge feature --no-ff -m "commit msg"
```

For some reasons (the working directory is not clean, the commits contain a lot of changes) I don't want to run `git checkout master`. How to merge current `feature` branch into `master` with `--no-ff` option without checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not have a so call "porcelain" command ready to be used easily to achieve the desired task. But all tools necessary to construct the merge commit do exist, of course. These commands are called "plumbing". You would do it like this:

```
cmtid=$(git commit-tree -p master -p feature \
   -m "commit msg" feature^{tree})
git branch -f master $cmtid
```

That is, firstly, a commit is constructed that has `master` as first parent and `feature` as second parent. The tree is identical to that of `feature`. `git commit-tree` prints the commit name, which we capture in a shell variable. Secondly, branch `master` is pointed to the commit that was just constructed.

Comment: `git commit-tree` will always have a special place in my heart as the one underrated git command. Upvoted.

Comment: Not OP's question, I know, but is there something similar that would perform the merge, in the case where `main` also had commits that `feature` didn't have?

Comment: @joanis See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483793/9917000

Comment: @joanis Look up [git merge-tree --write-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree). But things tend to become quite messy if there are merge conflicts. However, if there are none, then it should as trivial as to replace `feature^{tree}` in the above recipe by the output of `git merge-tree`.

Comment: Thanks! That should be easy to script, with an abort on merge conflict but proceed by default. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Git requires that you have checked out a branch before it makes a merge commit, the only exception is a fast forward.

The easiest in your situation is making a new worktree from master, then inside that worktree merging the branch, before deleting the worktree

```bash
git worktree add master
cd master
git merge feature --no-ff -m "commit msg"
# Do other things
cd ..
git worktree remove master
```